# Serving django from sub-folder in dev: static files not resolving

Tags: python, django, nginx

So, I'm using nginx to serve my django app from `/my_app/`:

`location /my_app/ {
       proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000/;
   }`

And I have `STATIC_URL = '/my_app/static`

Then, when using the django admin, the request to `/my_app/static/admin/css/base.css` resolves to `static/admin/css/base.css`. So, it doesn't match any static files (since django expect `/my_app/static/...` as a prefix).

So, my solution (in dev), is to serve the static files via my own "static file serving":

```
] + static('/static/', document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

But I get some crazy `TypeError at /static/admin/css/base.css` because my STATIC_ROOT is empty (I was thinking that in dev it should use the STATIC_ROOT). If I set the STATIC_ROOT to anything, it doesn't resolve too (looks like it's really trying to serve from a static directory instead of dynamically resolving).

Sooo, how to serve my django app from a sub-folder such that in dev it serves the static files dynamically ?

EDIT: even with `FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME = '/my_app/` it's not working and also the links in the django admin are wrong too but that's expected

EDIT 2: Since Django 1.10, the admin links are now correct (respecting SCRIPT_NAME): https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/releases/1.10/#django-contrib-admin

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you're serving the static files through Nginx.  The proxy pass is taking requests to the django domain and passing them to something else on the backend - What are you using to serve the base app?  Assuming it's something other than runserver (don't do this!),  gunicorn/uwsgi serve the django app, not static files.  Nginx generally passes the django requests through to Gunicorn or similar, and serves the static files.

My base configuration for Nginx looks like this.

```
server {
        server_name mydomain.com www.mydomain.com;

        access_log off;

        location /static/ {
            alias /var/www/mydomain.com/static/;
        }

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                add_header P3P 'CP="ALL DSP COR PSAa PSDa OUR NOR ONL UNI COM NAV"';
        }
    }
```

I'd recommend building your file paths in python, so that they're not hard coded.  For some initial overhead in setting it up, you get a lot of flexibility.   You can check where these resolve by going into the shell and importing them.

The static settings in settings.py (actually common.py, but the effect is the same) are then:

```
PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'static'),]
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(PROJECT_DIR)
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

In the above example, the project root obviously sits at /var/www/mydomain.com . These settings then work in both dev/locally and in production.

Comment: here my goal is to serve the app with the development server since I want to do the dev with full integration of nginx. On your config, you're serving directly from the root, that's why it easy + you're using the default `/static/` url. So, that's not very helpful for my case but thanks.

Comment: This would not work due to https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/25598, links to static files will be broken (`/static...` instead of expected `/myapp/static/...`)